# Why does xarray DataArray only contain NaNs after combining it with a xarray DataSet?

Tags: python, pandas, nan, python-xarray

I want to create daily histograms from a pandas Dataframe (df) and export them to xarray to combine it with another Dataset (data).  When I create the DataArray I can access it without problems, but once I combine it with the Dataset the array I added only consists of nan-entries. I think I made sure that all coordinates correctly align, by normalizing the time coordinate and making sure that the spatial coordinates are the same. Something is going wrong and I am running out of ideas. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
df=pd.read_csv(filepath+dfname)
data=xr.open_dataset(filepath+bgc_xarray)

df['date'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
data['time'] = data.indexes['time'].normalize()

xedges = np.arange(lonmin,lonmax+2*spacing,spacing)
yedges = np.arange(latmin,latmax+2*spacing,spacing)
latitude = xedges[:-1]
longitude = yedges[:-1]    

for i in range(2):
    df_i=df[df['date'] == data.time[i].values]

    x = df_i['cell_ll_lon']
    y = df_i['cell_ll_lat']
    weights = df_i['fishing_hours']
    hist, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(x, y, bins=(xedges, yedges), weights=weights)
    fishing_effort = hist.T 

    Xarray_i = xr.DataArray(
        data=fishing_effort,
        dims=['longitude', 'latitude'],
        coords=dict(
            longitude=(['longitude'], longitude),
            latitude=(['latitude'], latitude),
            time = data.time[i].values),
        attrs=dict(
            description='Fishing Effort',
            units='hours',),)
    
    if i == 0:
        Xarray = Xarray_i
    else:
        Xarray = xr.concat([Xarray, Xarray_i], 'time')
        
data['fishing_effort'] = Xarray
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh ok, the problem was with the spatial coordinates apparently. This fixed it:

```
longitude=(['longitude'], data.longitude.values),
latitude=(['latitude'], data.latitude.values),
```